What inconsistencies arise from a first, or uncaused cause?
If it's uncaused it didn't begin, but then if it causes something, that itself couldn't begin thus the effect must have been coexisting.
If it's uncaused, it means it can't be reached via external operations, but if it transfers information in causation, an effect would inherit its uncaused information in a state change, but then it would be caused in the effect.
If there is a first cause that can't change, where does change come from?
If change had to come from it, then state change would have been caused, but going from cause to effect is already a state change.
What other objections are there?

Uncaused causes do not have to be "first", and why "if it's uncaused it didn't begin"? Assuming there is free will, all our free choices will be "uncaused causes", but they sure do begin (and end).

@Conifold That is actually too a good objection. Non-determinism implies a state of which the occurrence is independent of prior states.

"first cause"->"didn't begin" - so far so good! But: "no begin" -> "no causation" is a false conclusion.... Or do you know/remember (y)our "very first ancients"?

It's getting very simple/cool/logic (but very unprofitable ), if "first cause" == (or <-) "final cause" ..

You are discussing and using the term "a first cause"... singular.  Why singular.  Why not many first causes?
